# formatDate() returns 'medium' when called 'short' in Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento1.9.2.3

I recently did an upgrade from Magento 1.8.0.0 to 1.9.2.3. Since then the Core Helper Function `formatDate()` returns the `'medium'`-formatted date, even if called with `'short'`.

Example (output from magerun dev:console):

Magento 1.8.0.0:

```
>>> Mage::helper('core')->formatDate('2011-06-28 08:50:51', 'short')
=> "28.06.11"
>>> Mage::helper('core')->formatDate('2011-06-28 08:50:51', 'medium')
=> "28.06.2011"
```

Magento 1.9.2.3:

```
>>> Mage::helper('core')->formatDate('2011-06-28 08:50:51', 'short')
=> "28.06.2011"
>>> Mage::helper('core')->formatDate('2011-06-28 08:50:51', 'medium')
=> "28.06.2011"
```

As far as I can see the `formatDate()` itself didn't change. Also my system configuration didn't change. Is it a bug? Can anybody reproduce? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Magento CE 1.8.1.0, [`Mage_Core_Model_Locale::getDateFormat()`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.8.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php#L412) always returns a four digit year part, no matter which date format is passed in.

To create the desired output format, you need to bypass the [`Mage_Core_Helper_Data::formatDate()`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.8.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php#L156) method.

Comment: ah ok, I see. Didn't know it's 4 digits because of ISO. It did break some 3rd party module but in that case I leave it as is and better fix that extension. Thanks!